# Populate Data from SQLLite db for Android using Phonegap

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova

I am using SQLLite for my phonegap based application for Android.The problem I am facing is that as long as the App is open,I am able to fetch whatever data that I store in the local.db file.
For e.g I have a settings feature where a user could save his/her settings and it goes to the db.Now the problem I am facing is that I am unable to fetch the data that the user has saved once the application is closed,I can get the data as long as the Application is open.
So the issue is the database isnt persistent. Can anybody tell how to store data in memory even when the Application is closed??

This is my mainActivity file

```
public class Demo extends CordovaActivity 
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.init();
        super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl());            
        try {
            String pName = this.getClass().getPackage().getName();
            this.copy("Databases.db", "/data/data/" + pName + "/app_database/");
            this.copy("0000000000000001.db", "/data/data/" + pName
                    + "/app_database/file__0/");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    void copy(String file, String folder) throws IOException {

        File CheckDirectory;
        CheckDirectory = new File(folder);
        if (!CheckDirectory.exists()) {
            CheckDirectory.mkdir();
            InputStream in = getApplicationContext().getAssets().open(file);
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(folder + file);

        // Transfer bytes from in to out
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0)
            out.write(buf, 0, len);
        in.close();
        out.close();
        }
    }
}
```

And these are the permissions I have given :-

```
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

After moving the copy code to the if condition as mentioned by **NigelK** did the trick.But after uninstalling the build and creating a fresh build is giving me the following error:-

```
01-10 16:11:34.466: E/SQLiteLog(29253): (1) no such table: CacheGroups
01-10 16:11:34.466: D/WebKit(29253): ERROR: 
01-10 16:11:34.466: D/WebKit(29253): Application Cache Storage: failed to execute statement "DELETE FROM CacheGroups" error "no such table: CacheGroups"
01-10 16:11:34.466: D/WebKit(29253): external/webkit/Source/WebCore/loader/appcache/ApplicationCacheStorage.cpp(558) : bool WebCore::ApplicationCacheStorage::executeSQLCommand(const WTF::String&)
01-10 16:11:34.466: E/SQLiteLog(29253): (1) no such table: Caches
01-10 16:11:34.466: D/WebKit(29253): ERROR: 
01-10 16:11:34.466: D/WebKit(29253): Application Cache Storage: failed to execute statement "DELETE FROM Caches" error "no such table: Caches"
01-10 16:11:34.466: D/WebKit(29253): external/webkit/Source/WebCore/loader/appcache/ApplicationCacheStorage.cpp(558) : bool WebCore::ApplicationCacheStorage::executeSQLCommand(const WTF::String&)
01-10 16:11:34.466: E/SQLiteLog(29253): (1) no such table: Origins
01-10 16:11:34.466: D/WebKit(29253): ERROR: 
01-10 16:11:34.466: D/WebKit(29253): Application Cache Storage: failed to execute statement "DELETE FROM Origins" error "no such table: Origins"
01-10 16:11:34.466: D/WebKit(29253): external/webkit/Source/WebCore/loader/appcache/ApplicationCacheStorage.cpp(558) : bool WebCore::ApplicationCacheStorage::executeSQLCommand(const WTF::String&)
01-10 16:11:34.476: E/SQLiteLog(29253): (1) no such table: DeletedCacheResources
```

Any idea on how to go about this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your database is persistent, the problem is that everytime your app starts, the calls to the copy() method made in onCreate() overwrite the database again with the copies held in Assets. I imagine you only want to make that copy once. One way is to only do the copy if the destination directory didn't already exist:

```
if (!CheckDirectory.exists()) {
    CheckDirectory.mkdir();
    ...move the copy code inside this if block
}
```

Or you could store a flag in Shared Preferences and set to true when you make the copies. In onCreate, only do the copies if that flag is false.

EDIT:

To use a shared preferences flag:

In onCreate:

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("MYPREFS", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);

//If no shared prefs exist, e.g. first install, it doesn't matter - the following will return false as a default
Boolean database_copied = sp.getBoolean("database_copied", false);

if (!database_copied)
{
    try {
        String pName = this.getClass().getPackage().getName();
        this.copy("Databases.db", "/data/data/" + pName + "/app_database/");
        this.copy("0000000000000001.db", "/data/data/" + pName
                + "/app_database/file__0/");
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("database_copied", true);
        editor.apply();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah moving the copy code to the if condition did the trick.Thanks a lot :)

Comment: NigelK : Uninstalling the previous build and creating a fresh build is showing me an error now. This is the error i am getting :-              E/SQLiteLog(26682): (1) no such table: CacheGroups . Any Idea what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: I have updated my question with the error log,please check and let me know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I would expect the uninstall to delete the /app_database/ folder. However it appears not, so the copy code doesn't run. My other suggestion to use SharedPreferences is probably more robust. Feel free to unaccept my answer if you wish since more people will pay attention to your question once more.

Comment: Doesn't the sharedPreferences flag would also be cleared on uninstalling the App?

Comment: Yes, shared preferences are cleared on an uninstall which is actually key. When you read the preference, you can specify a default where it does not exist. Please see my edit.

Comment: Yeah setting the way you mentioned has worked.Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I used same code to set my Pre-populated DB but for android OS 4.4.0+ version i am getting error as error processing SQL. My code works for below 4.4 versions.
what should i do to resolve this error for android v4.4+

Comment: @umesh This question was about how and when to run the database copy code, not about issues with the copy code or the database itself. Please raise a new question detailing the issue you have with setting up your database.

Answer (score 0):

just create a blank database and replace it with new assets DB..

```
Thread getData = new Thread() {
        public void run() {

            Data.qh = new QueryHandler(mContext); // for creating a blank DB
            DB_PATH = getDatabasePath("htest.sqlite").getAbsolutePath(); // get the path of blank DB
            copyDataBase(mContext);

        };
    };


void copyDataBase(Context mContext) {

        try {

            String outFileName = DB_PATH;

            OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;

            InputStream myInput = mContext.getAssets().open("htest.sqlite");
            while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            myInput.close();

            myOutput.flush();
            myOutput.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the sample code, this is to implement in html page in Javascript calls

```
function onDeviceReady() 
{
  var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 200000);
  db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
}
```

Then we you have to populate data in Table,call the method

```
function populateDB(tx) 
{
  var id=$('#id').val();
  var firstname=$('#firstname').val();        
  tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEMO (id unique, firstname)');
  tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, firstname) VALUES (?, ?)', [id, firstname]);
}
```

to Save data, do like following on any event

```
<button class="button" id="clickMe" onclick="onDeviceReady();" >Save</button>
```

Comment: I have already done what you have said,actually the problem is the database isnt fetching the saved records in case the application is closed,otherwise it works just fine when the application is open.